# Angular 2 handling isolated child components

Tags: angular

In below code i have developed reusable popup. i have 2 buttons and 2 child popup component elements. when i click on popup modal 1 i want to open modal 1 popup and when i click on modal 2 popup i want to open second popup.

logic i was applying was to send Modal1 id of Modal 1 on click function as

Please help or suggest correct way to do it as i am new to it.

```js
// Parent Component
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
tableData: any;
selectedTab: any = 'myRequisitions';
@ViewChild(PopupComponent) PC: PopupComponent;

open(i) {
    this.PC.open(i);
  }

  close(i) {
    this.PC.close(i);
  }

// child popup component

export class PopupComponent implements OnInit {

showPopup = false;
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.elRef.nativeElement.id);

  }

  open(i) {
    console.log(i); // get modal 1 and modal 2 values
    this.showPopup = true;
  }

  close(i) {
    this.showPopup = false;
  }
```

```html
<!-- ParentComponent  Start -->

<parent>

<!-- popup child 1 -->
<button (click)="open('modal1')">Open Modal 1</button>
<app-popup id="modal1">Modal 1</app-popup>


<!-- popup child 1 -->
<button (click)="open('modal2')">Open Modal 2</button>
<app-popup id="modal2">Modal 2</app-popup>

</parent>

<!-- ParentComponent End -->


<!-- PopupComponent Start -->

<div class="background" *ngIf="showPopup" #popup>

  <div class="content">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- PopupComponent  End -->
```

Comment: you might want to look at this https://github.com/ncstate-sat/popover

Comment: I want to create my own as per my management requirement